# Novice friendly way of calling two functions sequentially in JS

Tags: javascript

Sorry to ask a question that seems to have been answered at length in countless ways, I understand the asynchronous nature of JS, but the countless treatises on promises and callbacks I've read hasn't helped me produce working code.

I have 2 functions that interact with an API, and I just want to be able to call them in a way where one will run after the other.

These are my two functions:

```
let pveNextid = "";
function getNextID() {
  var clientServerOptions = {
   method: 'GET',
   uri: apiRoot + "/cluster/nextid",
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': pveCookie,
   }

  }
  request(clientServerOptions, function(error, response) {
    pveNextid = JSON.parse(response.body).data;
    console.log("Next VMID: " + pveNextid);

  })
}

// Create a new container with specs defined in conf.js

function newContainer() {
  var clientServerOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: apiRoot + "/nodes/" + conf.pveNode + "/lxc",
    form: {
      net0: "bridge=vmbr0,name=eth0,ip6=auto",
      ostemplate: conf.pveTemplate,
      vmid: pveNextid,
      unprivileged: 1,
      storage: "local-lvm",
      memory: 320,

    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Cookie': pveCookie,
      'CSRFPreventionToken': pveCSRF,
    }
  }
  request(clientServerOptions, function(error, response) {
    console.log(response.body);
})
};
```

There must be a simple, as in a few readable lines, way of doing this?

Comment: Search for async/await in JS (ES6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to provide a callback to the functions to give you a hook to run some code after the request completes, you can get rid of the global variable too this way:

```
// Take a callback here
function getNextID(callback) {
  var clientServerOptions = {
   method: 'GET',
   uri: apiRoot + "/cluster/nextid",
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': pveCookie,
   }

  }
  request(clientServerOptions, function(error, response) {
    var pveNextid = JSON.parse(response.body).data;
    console.log("Next VMID: " + pveNextid);
    // call the callback and give it the information you want to provide to the function
    callback(pveNextid);

  })
}

// Create a new container with specs defined in conf.js
// take the pveNextid here 
function newContainer(pveNextid) {
  var clientServerOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: apiRoot + "/nodes/" + conf.pveNode + "/lxc",
    form: {
      net0: "bridge=vmbr0,name=eth0,ip6=auto",
      ostemplate: conf.pveTemplate,
      vmid: pveNextid,
      unprivileged: 1,
      storage: "local-lvm",
      memory: 320,

    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Cookie': pveCookie,
      'CSRFPreventionToken': pveCSRF,
    }
  }
  request(clientServerOptions, function(error, response) {
    console.log(response.body);
})
};
// call getNextId and provide the callback here that you want to run after the first request
getNextId(newContainer);
```

I'd suggest promises and async/await and other more maintainable solutions over callbacks all the way down, however in this case it is a simple solution.

Comment: Thank you, I understand callbacks a little better now seeing it in this context. Adding some promise videos to my watch list.